# Compute Taylor error of $10^{-5}$ for $\cos(\pi/20)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, estimation

I need to calculate $\cos(\pi/20)$ with an error less than $10^{−5}$ of Taylor/Maclaurin series, What I did is like that:

$$|R_n(X)|=\left|\frac{(-1)^nC}{(n+1)!}\right|=\left|\frac{C}{(n+1)!}\right|_{0<C<\frac{\pi}{20}}<\frac{\frac{\pi}{20}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{\pi}{20(n+1)!}<10^{-5}$$

The statement is true when n=7, is my answer correct?

Comment: How do you get $>\frac{\frac{\pi}{20}}{(n+1)!}$ and how  would this help?

Comment: @gammatester it is the opposite sorry, I just made a mestake, it is $<$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. You wrote $R_2(X)$, but I suppose that you meant $R_n(X)$. Furthermore,$$\left|R_n\left(\frac\pi{20}\right)\right|\leqslant\frac{\left(\frac\pi{20}\right)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$Using the fact that $\pi<4$ (and that therefore $\frac\pi{20}<\frac15$), you can see that taking $n=4$ is enough.

Comment: It is $\frac{\pi}{20}$ and not $(\frac{\pi}{20})^{n+1}$

Comment: I am using the [Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder). Which formula are you using?

Comment: sorry you are correct, I made a mistake here, but isn't the function $R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}*(c)}{(n + 1)!} * (x − x0)^{n+1}$, where the C goes? does it disappear because the f'(x)= 1 or -1 always?

Comment: It is not $f^{(n+1)}*(c)$; it is  $f^{(n+1)}(c)$. And $f^{(n+1)}=\pm\cos$ or $\pm\sin$. In both cases, $|f^{(n+1)}(c)|\leqslant1$.

Comment: Thanks I understand it now